# Starting A service from a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Iam trying to start a service,which updates some data to spreadsheet, from a broadcast receiver. But Iam getting an Error that says UNABLE TO INSTANTIATE SERVICE : NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.
My Receiver code is:

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Pallav on 4/27/2015.
 */
public class InternetReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (isOnline(context)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available Do operations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateToSpreadsheet.class);
            context.startService(updateIntent);
        }

    }


    public boolean isOnline(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //should check null because in air plan mode it will be null
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());

    }
}
```

The code for my Service is:

```
public class UpdateToSpreadsheet extends Service {
D

BAdapter db;
    Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //some code
}
```

I have registered the Service and the Receiver in the Manifest file and have added all the permissions.The receiver is also working fine.I am confused what is the Problem with my Code. Please help me out.

Comment: `DBAdapter db;` db is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, please [examine LogCat to see where you are crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

In this case, Der Golem would appear to be correct. Not only are you attempting to do database I/O on the main application thread (bad!), you are trying to do so in an initializer of the `Service`. `db` is `null`, and so you cannot call methods on `db`.

You are going to need to move your `db.getAllContacts()` call into the body of your service, after `db` has been initialized, and on a background thread.

Comment: I tried what You said Sir, But it is not working... I am pretty much new to Android so please guide me if I am wrong. I am trying to update the contacts in my sqlite database to the google spreadsheet

Comment: Please provide me a proper example

Comment: Iam not getting the error now, but my service is still not running

Comment: Ok i think I got what my mistake was. Thank you very much